# Not able to create stub for SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to generate stub for web service but getting below error:

```
C:\Users\abdam>wsimport -Xauthfile  C:\Users\abdamda\Desktop\authFile.txt -keep -verbose http://abcd.sap.xyz.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A1011D1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/scs/sap/pqr?sap-client=300
```

parsing WSDL...

```
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
line 1 of http://abcd.sap.xyz.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A1011D1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/scs/sap/pqr?sap-client=300

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your question to include the relevant code

Comment: As per the error your schema has duplicate elements